# how to get output of specific "exit code" for each code in "for" loop?

Tags: batch-file

I want to get particular exit code for each output in for loop which I am printing(echo). I want to use that exit code and give particular output.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do ping -n 3 %%i >nul && if /i "ERRORLEVEL" == "0" (
    echo %%i Alive
) else (
        echo %%i Failed 
)
```

Comment: There's practically no information here, and what little _is_ written here is barely in English, but I _think_ you're looking for `%ERRORLEVEL%`. Except you're inside of a `for` loop so you need to enable delayed expansion and use `!ERRORLEVEL!`. I'm writing this as a comment instead of an answer because I can't actually tell what you're asking.

Comment: I have a for loop which outputs 4 lines.....of ping output....I have silenced the ping output...i need the each line and use its exit code and output regarding it

Comment: Nice, it's the exact thing I thought it was.

Comment: How to do that....im still not getting output

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to get the `errorlevel` by literally specifying it for each result. The `exitcode`/`errorlevel` can be evaluated by using conditional operators `&&` and `||`

So all you need is:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("list.txt") do ping -n 3 %%i >nul 2>&1 && echo %%i Alive || echo %%i Failed
```

What happens is simple. The `errorlevel` or `exit` code is evaluated. If it the `errorlevel` is `0` it is a success and it will use the `&&` operator to fire the next command. if it is `1` or larger, it will constitute as an error and it will use the or operator `||` and perform the relevent command.

If however you MUST use the `errorlevel` or `%errorlevel` literally:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("list.txt") do (
    ping -n 3 %%i >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 (
         echo %%i Failed
    ) else (
        echo %%i Alive
  )
)
```

Obviously without needing `delayedexpansion`

Comment: sorry...but for me there is a need and my program says i should take errorlevel for each command        How do i do it

Comment: It does. Just not directly apecifying it. The conditional operators act on errorlevels so && is if errorlevel < 1 and || if 1 or up.

Comment: I've added the option of using `errorlevel` literally.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer to your problem, as you stated it, is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do ping -n 3 %%i >nul 2>&1 & if "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
    echo %%i Alive
) else (
    echo %%i Failed 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
 set "reported="
 ping -n 3 %%i >nul
 call echo %%i responded with errorlevel %%errorlevel%%
 if errorlevel 2 set "reported=y"&echo errorlevel 2 actions&cd .
 if errorlevel 1 set "reported=y"&echo errorlevel 1 actions&cd .
 if not defined reported echo errorlevel 0 actions
)
```

The string `"ERRORLEVEL"` will never be equal to the string `"0"`. You are looking for the ***value*** of `errorlevel`, which would normally be `%errorlevel%` **BUT** since you have used a `code block` (a parenthesised sequence of statements) `%errorlevel%`, like any variable would be replaced by its value at the time the code block is encountered, not as it changes when executed. See Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947

You can use `if errorlevel?` as shown, but you must interrogate `errorlevel` in reverse-order as `if errorlevel n` is true for `errorlevel` being *n* or **greater than *n***.

The code shown will set `errorlevel` to `0` (using `cd .`) after whatever actions you choose to execute so any change to `errorlevel` made by those actions is overridden and will not cause any of the other `errorlevel` actions to be executed. If none of the actions is executed, `reported` will remain undefined, so the fact that it's undefined tells us that the original `errorlevel` was `0`.